# Stubbing a computed function in vue with Cypress

Tags: vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to stub this out in Cypress. I have a computed that returns true or false. I just want it to return true.

```
  computed: {

      isAdmin() {
          return this.$store.state.User.isRegistered &&
           this.$store.state.User.isAdmin
        }
}
```

There is a great article on using the vuex store

https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/

but I don't even want to touch the store. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Havent tested this but it should go like this:

```
        cy.stub(YourComponent.computed, 'isAdmin').callsFake(() => { return true })
```